# update dictionary in nested array of dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I want to update the list2 based on the values in the opti array, in a way so that it check if the nested array has a dict with the key 'RSI_15' and then update the dict with the key "val" in the same array, and so on for all the arrays in the opti array.

right now my output is this

```
[['random', {'ind': 'RSI_15'}, {'cond': '<'}, {'val': 1000}], ['random', {'ind': 'volume'}, {'cond': '>'}, {'val': 1000}]]
```

so clearly my for loop overwrites it, but i cant crack the logic

my wished output is this:

```
[['random', {'ind': 'RSI_15'}, {'cond': '<'}, {'val': 15}], ['random', {'ind': 'volume'}, {'cond': '>'}, {'val': 1000}]]
```

code:

```
list2 = [['random', {'ind': 'RSI_15'}, {'cond': '<'}, {'val': 12}], ['random', {'ind': 'volume'}, {'cond':
                                                                                               '>'}, {'val': 44}]]

opti = [['RSI_15', 15], ['volume', 1000]]

def update_val(indicator, val, values):
    flag = False
    for v in values:
        if isinstance(v, dict) and flag == False:
            try:
                v['ind'] = indicator
                flag = True
            except:
                continue
        if isinstance(v, dict) and flag == True:
            try:
                if v['val'] :
                    v['val'] = val
                    flag = True
            except:
                continue
        

def up(conds, opti_val):
    for cond in conds:
        for item in opti_val:
            update_val(item[0], item[1], cond)
    return conds



list2 = up(list2, opti)
print(list2)
```

Comment: `v['ind'] == indicator` doesn't do anything. It compares the indicator, but it's not part of an `if` so nothing happens.

Comment: oh was a typo that sneaked itself in , in the last minute, was suposed to be v['ind'] = indicator

Comment: Why do you want to change `v['ind']`? You just want to search for a matching indicator.

Comment: is the order of the sublists important? Would I get the same result swapping the inputs like so `opti = [['volume', 1000], ['RSI_15', 15]]`?

Comment: @alec_djinn the idea is that same result should be given

Comment: @SomaJuice then I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't figure out how your logic is supposed to work, since you have the comparison `v['ind'] == indicator` outside a conditional statement.

But it can be simplified greatly using the `any()` function to search a list, rather than your loop with the confusing `flag` variable.

```
def update_val(indicator, val, values):
    if any(isinstance(v, dict) and v.get('ind') == indicator for v in values):
        for v in values:
            if isinstance(v, dict) and 'val' in v:
                v['val'] = val;
                break
```

Comment: oooohhhh boy, i am gonna use any() from now on :D , goodbye convoluted for loops! thanks alot man!

Comment: Yes, it's a very useful function.

Comment: You should also consider redesigning your data structure. Lists should generally have uniform data, and a list of dictionaries that each have a different key is an anti-pattern. Why isn't the list a dictionary like `{'type': 'random', 'ind': 'RSI_15', 'cond': <', 'val': 15}`?

Comment: yes that is a good point, but it has to be this convuluted way i am afraid

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is overly convoluted. You can do all with a single function operating on your particular data structure. Also, it is probably better not to modify the input but returning a modified copy instead. Although, this will be ultimately your decision.
Finally, you can use for/else instead flagging when breaking a loop.

Here is a simple implementation

```
def update(input_data, input_calls):
    for _id, ind, cond, val in input_data:
        for call in input_calls:
            if ind['ind'] in call:
                yield [_id,
                       {'ind': ind['ind']},
                       {'cond': cond['cond']},
                       {'val': call[-1]} #here it updates the value
                      ]
                break
        else:
            yield row
 
input_data = [['random', {'ind': 'RSI_15'}, {'cond': '<'}, {'val': 12}], ['random', {'ind': 'volume'}, {'cond':'>'}, {'val': 44}]]
input_calls = [['ddd', 1000], ['volume', 1000], ['RSI_15', 15]] #testing odd calls

updated_data = list(update(input_data, input_calls))

print(updated_data)
#[['random', {'ind': 'RSI_15'}, {'cond': '<'}, {'val': 15}], ['random', {'ind': 'volume'}, {'cond': '>'}, {'val': 1000}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Following your logic with for loops, here's an improved approach:

```
for opt in opti:                                                                                                                      
    for sublist in list2:                                                                                                             
        indicator_detected = False                                                                                                    
        for elem in sublist:                                                                                                          
            if isinstance(elem, dict):                                                                                                
                if list(elem.values())[0] == opt[0]:                                                                                  
                    indicator_detected = True                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                      
        if indicator_detected:                                                                                                        
            for elem in sublist:                                                                                                      
                if isinstance(elem, dict):                                                                                            
                    if list(elem.keys())[0] == 'val':                                                                                 
                        elem['val'] = opt[1]
```

That said, checking whether one of the elements of each sublist is a dictionary and whether that dictionary has a given key can be written in a less cumbersome (and probably faster) way using `any` and comprehensions, as other answers show.